# pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short error in postgres

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore, database-dump

I am trying to dump the database in my local system by using the command :

```
pg_restore --host=localhost --port=5432 --dbname=dev_db --no-owner --no-privileges db_dump_new.backup
```

but I am getting the error :

```
pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My initial guess would be that the problem was with the pg_dump rather than the pg_restore.   How big is the db_dump_new.backup file?

Answer (score 16):

If you're using docker and redirecting the dump file from your local machine, don't forget `-i`. This won't work:

```
docker exec <container> pg_restore -U "$USER" < ./localfile.dump;
```

Be sure that the docker container can see standard in with the `-i` option! This should work:

```
docker exec -i <container> pg_restore -U "$USER" < ./localfile.dump;
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same error.  In my case I had simply neglected to specify the backup file at the end of the command.

Comment: ended up with very same error because lost `\` of multiline bash script....

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used docker

```
$ docker exec a5f7b094c523 pg_restore -d my_new_db < "./2256.dump"
pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)
```

And the issue was that "./2256.dump" is not a binary file but a plain sql text dump.

To check that just do

```
$ head ~/2256.dump                                                                                                    
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 10.8 (Ubuntu 10.8-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 10.8 (Ubuntu 10.8-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
```

And to import sql dump fo

```
$ pv ~/2256.dump |docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml -T db psql "fight-round3"
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but my dump file *is* binary. Any clues there?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command, it will work perfectly to restore the db file using sql file in Postgres 13 in pgadmin 4

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin>psql -U user_name db_name< D:\dbfile\sql_file.sql
```